# How do I restore a deleted perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perspectives

I accidentally deleted the C/C++ perspective in Eclipse through the Preferences window, but all of the CDT tools are still there. How do I get back the perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the perspective on accident or did you actually `delete` it completely?

Have you tried to find it in `Window -> Open Perspective -> Other`? See if it is there.

Comment: accidentally deleted it. its not like i need the c/c++ persp that much but this has happened to me with other perspectives before